# x-template has trouble displaying value on the v-for

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I had this issue while trying to render html into a vue component.
I am trying to insert component html through x-template. The issue is when I was trying to display the value  `{{i.value}}` like this it was throwing error on console.

```
<script type="text/x-template" id="first-template">
    <div>
         <ul>
           <li v-for="i in dataCollection">{{ i.id }}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</script>


Vue.component('menu', {
    template: '#first-template',
    data() {
        return {
            dataCollection: [{"id":"01"}, {"id":"02"}, {"id":"03"}],
        }
    }
});
```

The error on console was:

[image]

But when I was giving value as attribute like:

```
<script type="text/x-template" id="first-template">
    <div>
            <ul>
              <li v-for="i in dataCollection" :id="i.id"></li>
           </ul>
       </div>
</script>
```

it works perfect.

Anyone know any fix ?

Answer (score 1):

> You should not put script/x-template tages inside of the element that you mount to the main instance to. Vue 2.0 will read all of its content and try to use it as a template for the main instance, and Vue's virtualDOM treats script/x-template's like normal DOM, which screws everthing up,
>
> Simply moving the template out of the main element solved the problem.

[Source](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/4276#issuecomment-262192295)

Answer (score 0):

> In 2.2.0+, when using v-for with a component, a key is now required.

You can read about it here https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-a-Component

Comment: thank you for your reply. but its still showing same error on console that "i is not defined"

Comment: @HariGopal i don't have an error but may be you must rename your component to another name, because the menu is a reserved name, you can see it here https://jsfiddle.net/fazanaka/6snxmcmr/

Comment: already did that as i mensioned on my question attributes are loading fine                                                                                                         
`<li v-for="i in dataCollection" :id="i.id"></li>` , works fine

Answer (score 0):

This is a suggestion, not a answer.

As @DmitriyPanov mentioned, you'd better bind unique key when using `v-for`.

Another issue is you'd better to use non built-in/resevered html elements.

so change component id from `menu` to `v-menu` or else you like.

Then simulate similar codes below which are working fine.

I doubt the error is caused by some elements of `dataCollection` doesn't have key=id (probably you didn't post out all elements). You can try `{{ 'id' in i ? i.id : 'None' }}`.

```js
Vue.component('v-menu', { //
    template: '#first-template',
    data() {
        return {
            newDataCollection: [{"id":"01"}, {"id":"02"}, {"id":"03"}, {'xx':0}],
            dataCollection: [{"id":"01"}, {"id":"02"}, {"id":"03"}]
        }
    }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {testProperty: {
      'test': '1'
    }}
  },
  methods:{
    test: function() {
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<v-menu></v-menu>
</div>

<script type="text/x-template" id="first-template">
    <div>
      <div style="float:left;margin-right:100px;">
        <p>Old:</p>
         <ul>
           <li v-for="(i, index) in dataCollection" :key="index">{{  i.id }}</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>Adjusted:</p>
         <ul>
           <li v-for="(i, index) in newDataCollection" :key="index">{{ 'id' in i ? i.id : 'None' }}</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. i had tried all of your suggestions but its still showing same error on console that "i is not defined"

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here lies in the placement of the X-Template code (I had the same issue). According to the documentation:

> Your x-template needs to be defined outside the DOM element to which Vue is attached.

If you are using some kind of CMS, you might end up doing just that.

What helped me in that case was (based on your example):

1. Placing the X-template script outside the #app
2. passing the collection as a prop to the v-menu component:

```
<v-menu v-bind:data-collection="dataCollection"></v-menu>
```

3. list dataCollection as a prop inside the v-menu component:

```
Vue.component('v-menu', { //
    template: '#first-template',
    props: [ "dataCollection" ],
    ...
});
```

I hope that helps anyone.